# How add new column to deployed table in Azure without losing data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have already deployed ASP.NET MVC web application with DB in Azure. I use EF Code First.

Now I need to add column to table Users without losing any existing data. Should I use migrations or SQL Server Management Studio or something else? And how should I use it?

Comment: if you are going to use migrations, I highly recommend you backup first, scrap that i highly recommend you backup before trying something on live. The way i do it ATM as i haven't done enough code first testing with or without migrations, is: add the field in code, and then manual add to SQL then make sure that you do not have any code which will drop the DB if its different, deploy and your done. it may complain about your `__MigrationHistory` and therefore give errors, i just drop this table and your away.

Comment: So I insert to entity User property X, then insert the column X to database and then publish my code and it should work?

Comment: correct, PLEASE heed MY WARNINGS tho... do the whole thing in TEST first, until you feel comfortable. only reason i say this is you must be aware of drop and create if model is different, usually code first this could be i the context code.... and will wipe ur db if its on.

Comment: This didn't work because it said that the model changed... I had to use migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do the following:

1. enable-migrations
2. add property into the entity I wanted to change
3. add-migration
4. deploy